# If/Else validation not working like it should

Tags: javascript, extjs, if-statement

I am trying to get this validation to work and I am having some difficulties. This is the code that I have:

```
function validateCarsMinMax(v) {
      if (tfRateLoc1.getValue() > '0' && tfRateLoc2.getValue() > '0') {
          if (tfRateLoc3.getValue() != '0') {
              return '1B cannot contain a value if CW is entered';
          }
      } else return true
  }
```

It seems to not like the `&& tfRateLoc2.getValue() > '0'` line because it works just fine when I take it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: What would be the problem when the part is _not_ taken out? Syntax error? Wrong result?

Comment: This whole function has a smell to it. In one case you return a string, in another a boolean and in another you don't return anything. Doing things like this will be a source of bugs later on.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `getValue()` returns a number and '0' is a string not a number so the comparison incorrect.

```
if (tfRateLoc1.getValue() > 0 && tfRateLoc2.getValue() > 0) {
      if (tfRateLoc3.getValue() != 0) {
```

Other issue is you never return a value if `if (tfRateLoc3.getValue() != '0')` { is false

Comment: got rid of the string, changed them to number values and it still doesn't like that line

Comment: What does it return? You need to debug in the console.

Comment: Is getValue() returning a number or string? If a string, parseFloat() it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    function validateCarsMinMax(v){
    if (tfRateLoc1.getValue() > 0 || tfRateLoc2.getValue() > 0){
        if (tfRateLoc3.getValue() > 0){
         return '1B cannot contain a value if CW is entered';
        }
    } else return true     
}
```

Comment: LOL, really it is an && does not equal OR. It was a logic error and you still have a BUG in the code!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (parseInt(tfRateLoc1.getValue()) > 0 && parseInt(tfRateLoc2.getValue()) > 0
     && parseInt(tfRateLoc3.getValue()) != 0)
{
    return '1B cannot contain a value if CW is entered';
}else return true
```