# Combining 2 IF/ELSE statements (validation)

Tags: javascript, extjs, if-statement

I am trying to combine 2 IF/Else statements to create one validation function. This is my code for the 2 separate validations:

```
function validateCarsMin(v){
    if (tfRateLoc1.getValue() > 0 || tfRateLoc2.getValue() > 0){
        if (tfRateLoc3.getValue() > 0){
         return '1B cannot contain a value if CW is entered';
        }
    } else return true     
}

function validateRateLoc3(v){
    if (v != ''){
        if(tfRateLoc3.getValue() < tfRateLoc4.getValue()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return 'This Value is not valid';
        }}
}
```

I did not know if there was a best practice for this and it so, what would it be?

Thanks  for the help on the last question I had.

Comment: I know javascript is loosely typed but it shouldn't be abused, have the methods only return a boolean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If/Else validation not working like it should](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429354/if-else-validation-not-working-like-it-should)

Answer (score 0):

Change the functions to return either `true` or `false`.  You can push the `msgs` to an array to be used later.

```
var errorMsgs = [];

function validateCarsMin(){
    if (tfRateLoc1.getValue() > 0 || tfRateLoc2.getValue() > 0){
        if (tfRateLoc3.getValue() > 0){
           errorMsgs.push('1B cannot contain a value if CW is entered');
         return false;
        }
    } else{
       return true;
    }     
}

function validateRateLoc3(){
        if(tfRateLoc3.getValue() < tfRateLoc4.getValue()){
            return true;
        } else {
            errorMsgs.push('This Value is not valid');
            return false;
        }};
}

function validateForm(){
   var isValid = false;
   isValid = validateCarsMin();
   isValid = (!isValid) ? isValid:validateRateLoc3();
   return isValid;
}
```

**Note** I removed the `v` parameter because it seemed irrelevant.  It is not used in the first function and it creates a syntax error in the second.